# Cannot update page-break-before when range contains paragraphs in a table

Tags: c#, google-docs-api

```
UpdateParagraphStyleRequest paragraphStyle = new UpdateParagraphStyleRequest()
        {
            Fields = "*",
            ParagraphStyle = new ParagraphStyle()
            {
                SpaceAbove = new Dimension() {
                    Magnitude = 0,
                    Unit = "PT" // https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#unit
                },
                PageBreakBefore = null,
                NamedStyleType = "NORMAL_TEXT" // https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#namedstyletype
            },
            Range = new Range() { StartIndex = 1, EndIndex = 398 }
        };
```

[image]

The intention of the above code is, to do what can be done in the UI with the function "Remove space before paragraph". As you can see "Add page break before" is greyed out. The reason why it's greyed out, is because I am in this context inside a table. And inside a table this feature is apparently not available.

That's why the property "PageBreakBefore" is set to null, to indicate, that I don't want to update it. Because the range given in my code is also that table.

Nevertheless I am getting this error: "Cannot update page-break-before when the range contains paragraphs in a table".

Comment: I think it would be better if you could provide a full minimal reproducible example including a sample of the doc you have with dummy data so everyone can try to reproduce the behavior exactly with your current environment and help with your question.

Comment: Thanks for your input. A reproducible example would also include API keys, which I can't share. I guess to reproduce it, all you have to do is, create a document with a table and some rows and columns and then try to run the above code within the range of that table.

Answer (score 0):

I also spent some time to figure out how it should work.
Finnaly I found a way, the FIELD property should be set coorectly without wildcard.

```
UpdateParagraphStyleRequest paragraphStyle = new UpdateParagraphStyleRequest()
        {
            Fields = "alignment,namedStyleType,lineSpacing,your property",
            ParagraphStyle = new ParagraphStyle()
            {
                SpaceAbove = new Dimension() {
                    Magnitude = 0,
                    Unit = "PT" // https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#unit
                },
                PageBreakBefore = null, -- SHOULD BE REMOVED
                NamedStyleType = "NORMAL_TEXT" // https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#namedstyletype
            },
            Range = new Range() { StartIndex = 1, EndIndex = 398 }
        };
```